# Need help understanding python syntax

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Can someone explain the syntax on lines 5 & 16

```
   1 # Using the generator pattern (an iterable)
   2 class firstn(object):
   3     def __init__(self, n):
   4         self.n = n
   5         self.num, self.nums = 0, []
   6 
   7     def __iter__(self):
   8         return self
   9 
  10     # Python 3 compatibility
  11     def __next__(self):
  12         return self.next()
  13 
  14     def next(self):
  15         if self.num < self.n:
  16             cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1
  17             return cur
  18         else:
  19             raise StopIteration()
  20 
  21 sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
```

Answer (score 3):

That's tuple assignment; you can assign to multiple targets.

The right-hand expression is evaluated first, and then each value in that sequence is assigned to the names on left-hand side one by one, from left to right.

Thus, `self.num, self.nums = 0, []` assigns `0` to `self.num` and `[]` to `self.nums`.

See the [assigment statements documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> - If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.

Because the right-hand side portion is executed *first*, the line `cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1` assigns `self.num` to `cur` *after* calculating `self.num + 1`, which is assigned to `self.num`. If `self.num` was `5` before that line, then after that line `cur` is `5`, and `self.num` is 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.num, self.nums = 0, []
cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1
```

These are shorthands for the following:

```
self.num = 0
self.nums = []
```

and

```
cur = self.num
self.num = self.num + 1
```

As a personal preference, I would not use the compound assignments in either of these two lines. The assignments are not related, so there's no reason to combine them.

There are times when compound assignments can prove useful. Consider how one swaps two numbers in languages like C and Java:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

In Python we can eliminate the temporary variable!

```
a, b = b, a
```

Comment: Thank you both!  Now I see how simple it is.  I thought these were three statements separated by commas :)